# Solenoid flyback considerations in this pFET/nFET inversion circuit

Tags: mosfet, solenoid, flyback

I am trying to combine FETs, where logic permits, to reduce the size of a pcb. Is it poor practice to have the pFET's gate and nFET's drain shared by an inductive load that will usually be grounded through the same nFET? The voltage polarity and the Vg requirements against Vs of the pFET make me want to assume it seems feasible, but just want to be sure. Should the snubber diode be specified with a reverse breakdown as low as possible so as to *at all* protect the limitations of Vgs on the pFET, or will the snubber fully ensure no transients?

Thanks[image]

Comment: How is it constructed?

Comment: The coil controls a half inch fluid valve; about 20W continuous. Physically, the coil is separated from the housing containing the circuitry through a stainless wall (and the manufacturer coil housing packaging itself).

Comment: No, I mean the circuitry.

Comment: R2 was just added to regulate Ids of the nmos. The SW1 depicted is actually the output of a cmos logic IC that selectively goes high and low (a debounced SR latch). The system is used to adapt to this positive logic because the negative logic variant I was uncertain would behave within spec. The pMos will control an opto-isolated control line for a remote SSR that requires 12V supplied to it, in actuality a ~28mA draw @ ~400 ohm -- apologies for the generic values (likely inaccurate on L1). There is considerable distance between the pMos drain and load (~100 ft.)